# Apply div CSS before an animation starts instead of when it ends

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ovhWJdzoNw9vZ2EzcZ1r?p=preview) I have a jQuery UI animation (slideDown) that displays a div. The div also has a `margin-top:100px` attribute to show it `100px` below the top margin.

The problem is that when the animation starts, it disregards the margin, and it is only applied after the animation ends. I need the margin applied at the beginning of the animation. How to accomplish this?

HTML

```
<body style="background-color:blue">
   <div id="div1" style="background-color:orange;width:180px;height:40px;margin-top:100px"></div>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
 $(function() {
    var div1 = $('#div1');
    div1.hide();

    setTimeout(function(){
       div1.slideDown();
    }, 1000);

 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slideDown animation is starting from 0 and sliding the item down into it's final position.

If you want to it to slideDown from 100px from the top, add a wrapper.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="div1" style="background-color:orange;width:180px;height:40px;"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Now the animation will start at 100px from the top and slideDown just the div element.

http://plnkr.co/edit/yqYTonJEBuggTU4OsQ6o?p=preview

Side note, I see you have a DIV with ID 'div1' but in your CSS, you have a class definition for 'div1'. ID Selector is `#` where class selector is `.`. So you may consider changing it to `#div1 {}` in your CSS if you need.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
  <body style="background-color:blue">
  <div id="div1" class="div1"></div>
  </body>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function() {
    var div1 = $('#div1');
    var b = div1.position();
    div1.hide();
    setTimeout(function(){
        div1.slideDown({top: "+" + b.top});
    }, 1000); 
})
```

CSS

```
.div1 { width: 160px; height: 40px; position:absolute; border:1px solid black; background-color: orange; top: 50px; }
```

Please see my forked version of your Plunker.
[Position and then Animation](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/hy4CjgOVkE5pNFI6)